# Lotus script to move mass domino users mail databases from csv file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need a lotus script for mass move of users mail files from one domino directory to another. I've found script for mass user deletion and just replaced method `notesAdministrationProcess.DeleteUser` with method `noteID$ = notesAdministrationProcess .MoveMailUser`( username$ , newhomeserver$ , newhomeservermailpath$ ) , where is `newhomeservermailpath$` - `moved` - directory which I previously created to move mail files from default mail folder `mail`. Domino console didn't report any error but script doesn't move user's mail files. What is missing? Am I doing something wrong?

Script code:

```
Sub Initialize

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db,addbk As NotesDatabase
Dim usrvw As NotesView
Dim Username As String
Dim movecounter As Integer

Dim nap As NotesAdministrationProcess
Dim FIleNumber As Integer
Dim Filename As String

Set nap = session.CreateAdministrationProcess("MyServer/myserverdomain")

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase   

Set addbk=session.GetDatabase("MyServer/myserverdomain","names.nsf",0)

Set usrvw=addbk.getview("$NamesFieldLookup")


filenumber%=FreeFile()
    fileName$="D:\moveMail.csv"

Open fileName For Input As fileNumber%

On Error Resume Next

movecounter=0
Do Until EOF(fileNumber%)
    Input #fileNumber%,Username
    movecounter=movecounter+1
    Call nap.MoveMailUser(Username, MyServer/myserverdomain , moved)
    Print "Moved" & CStr(movecounter) "Users"
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: `MoveMailUser` just enters a request into Administration Requests database. AdminP process will later move user's mail file. Check Administration Requests database if your code added the requests properly.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought so but I tried this script yesterday and several times run: tell adminp process all but AdminP process didn't move any mail file.

Comment: The question is: Did you check admin4.nsf if the requests are created? It is possible, that these requests have to be confirmed in the database before they run...

Comment: Yes, I have checked Admin4 requests but there isn't any request for moving files. Maybe something is missing or wrong in above script code? Is this call method: Call nap.MoveMailUser(Username, MyServer/myserverdomain , moved) right?

Comment: "On Error Resume Next" is bad as it ignores errors. Remove it please and look where code fails. Your MoveMailUser code line can't work for several reasons if your code above is your real code.

Comment: To answer your question from the comments directly: NO, it's not right... the variable "moved" is not defined at all and MyServer/myserverdomain is a mathematic calculation and not a string literal...

Comment: "moved" is not the variable it is destination directory name (relative path - subdirectory of data directory) where I wanna move the mail files and "myServer/myserverdomain" is general name for mail  server name. That is the way "moveMailUser" method  syntax should look like - -> noteID$ = notesAdministrationProcess .MoveMailUser( username$ , newhomeserver$ , newhomeservermailpath$ )

Answer (score 3):

There are -as stated in comments- some major problems with your code:

First: NEVER use "On Error Resume Next" except for expected single errors you want to suppress.

Your case is the best example: Your code fails because of non defined variables, but you will never get an error message because you suppress it: No chance of knowing where it went wrong.

Second: EVER add

```
Option Declare
```

to any code you write in LotusScript. There is even a Designer setting to do this automatically. This option would have checked if all variables you use are declared... and would have not even allowed you to save this code.

Third: The errors in code. You managed to produce 2 errors when changing one single line of code...

This is how it looks:

```
Call nap.MoveMailUser(Username, MyServer/myserverdomain , moved)
```

This is how it should look:

```
Call nap.MoveMailUser(Username, "MyServer/myserverdomain" , "moved")
```

Just look at the difference... I will not start to teach you basics about variables vs. string literals as these are the same for almost every programming language.

-off topic-
One more thing: The way you approach business tasks is reckless at least but in any case very dangerous... You seem to copy some code from somewhere but even lack the very basics in coding. Seeing that you delete productive users and move productive mail databases I would be very concerned when I saw you doing this via "trial and error"... But this is just my point of view...
-/end off topic-

Comment: It was my oversight to use server name and destination directory without quotes. Of course I know the difference between variables and string literals. I didn't see the forest for the trees. Quotes solved the problem. Everything else is more or less fine in code. //off topic Of course I didn't try this code on production server. I have test environment for these things.//

Comment: One more thing - script works but after another test of moving mail files I noticed that mail files in source directory were not deleted, nap.MoveMailUser process just copied mail files to destination directory. I've checked "Pending Administrator Approval" and "All Requests by Server" in admin4, also "tell adminp process all" didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in the Administrator client, moving a user's mailfile consist of several steps, see https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/admn_moveamailfilefromoneservertoanother_r.html

- Check mail server's access
- Create new mail file replica
- Add new mail file fields
- Monitor new mail file fields
- Replace mail file fields
- (user has to login to Notes client, or you have to create AdminRequest programmatically)
- Push changes to new mail server
- Get mail file information for deletion
- Approve mail file deletion